# Problem with CheckBox in infopath 2010

Tags: list, workflow, infopath, dropdown

Hi my name is Marcelo ... I have a problem with extracting data from a list checkbox , i selected 2 options (or more than two of several existing) and these disappear after ... then I need to display them in a view .. but the problem is that the selected items are saved .. appreciate help ...

PD: Photo attached http://s974.beta.photobucket.com/user/Tellohave/media/1_zps2b19c707.png.html?sort=3&o=2

PD2: if "ambiente" is blank, "cuenta" field does not seem .. when "ambiente" exists, "cuenta" appears to the list as we see in picture 2, but after the drama is that I can not save the data and display .. as in picture 3

The Step of the flow is..

1 - The user opens the form

2 - The user completes the fields from the first view, which asks project code, date, temperature and accounts

3 - The user selects, environment .. which will bring the settings stored in the list environments and show them a list of accounts

4 - the user selects the accounts (accounts stored in the field) that appear in the field (can be more than one), this shows only the accounts that belong to the environment using a filter

5 - The user saves the form, hoping the supervisor approves

6 - The Responsible (or approver) checks the user login information, you can read all the camps, but that's the problem .. field accounts that the user had previously selected, is empty, then the flow falls

Comment: I do not see any checkbox in your screenshot. What do you mean under "list checkbox"?

Comment: Inthe field named "cuentas" it's a  lits checkbox or.. listbox multiple selection , a list you can choose multiple options , and this box appears when "ambiente" field exists, so does not appear in the screenshoot  , appears the field "cuenta" that lists filtering accounts belonging to an "ambiente" (I solved it with filter), the problem is that the items you selected, should be stored in another list to display them, and is there where I drop the program ... since it is not like taking the selected items in the list type.

Comment: So, why are you giving your own names to standard names of used Infopath controls?  I've read over your question few times and could not understand what you were asking Could you make available screenshots ( "picture 1", "picture 2",  "picture 3") or unambiguously identify them. Plz rewrite your phrase " but after the drama is that I can not save the data and display .. as in picture 3". It is not comprehensible